# Any tips on making pentatonic climbing more fluid (electric guitar)

Tags: guitar, electric-guitar, technique, scales

I've been practicing pentatonic scales on my electric guitar and sometimes it'll be very fluid and smooth sounding and other times it'll be very choppy and static. Is making the climb-up and climb-down solely based on picking technique?

Comment: It would be helpful to know if there are specific scales that are more problematic than others.

Comment: Could you post a video of yourself playing in which you have the problem so we can see better what is going on?

Answer (score 6):

I assume you are talking about the basic 2 notes per string pentatonic positions but just about anything you do on guitar is dependent on good coordination between BOTH hands. Of course you must have good picking technique but you must also have good left hand technique. You must synchronize the placing and releasing of your left hand fingers with the picking of the right hand.

When you are fluid and smooth your left hand is placing and releasing the notes in concert with the plucking of the right hand so the note durations are long and seem to flow onto each other. When you are choppy some possibilities are you might be plucking unevenly, or your plucking might be out of sync with the placing and releasing of your left hand fingers. Without watching and hearing you play it’s impossible to say why for sure.

Slow things down and break them into shorter segments. Start with 2 notes on one string then 4 notes on 2 strings then one octave. Start slowly and gradually increase the pace once you get consistency at slower tempos. That is easier and more effective than tying to play something fast from the start.

Comment: Also, moving to 3 notes per string can help change things up, sometimes allowing much more fluid progressions, but the same holds true: both hands need to work in synch

Comment: @DoktorMayhem I do agree with you but with pentatonics that involves switching positions as you ascend and descend which is a more advanced technique. Since the OP didn’t specify his level of proficiency I approached the question from the point of playing in simple vertical positions.

Comment: @DoktorMayhem - 3nps would work well using full scales, but as pents?

Answer (score 4):

Supplementary comment too big for a comment box.  My cello professor explained to me that when the brain sends one signal or instruction to the hands for each note, it is hard to achieve fluency.  So, John's last paragraph works great because you train your hands to respond to one instruction for a group of notes.

A variant of this is to play the first three notes of your sequence, rest for a beat, then another group of three, but starting with the third note of your sequence, etc.  Eventually your brain will be able to send the "start such and so sequence" to your hands and then they will do the rest, similar to how you can drive home on autopilot without thinking about the individual steps.

Comment: I like the idea variant you mentioned because you play the note that overlaps consecutively. Sometimes when I break things into segments for students they have trouble connecting the dots afterwards. Just to be clear for a 7 note line you would play 1-2-3-R-3-4-5-R-5-6-7-R ?

Comment: @JohnBelzaguy - yes.

Answer (score 3):

There are various techniques used in guitar playing which may help.

Hammering on to the higher note will keep upward movement smoother to play and smoother sounding too. As will pull-offs when going down - all on the same string.

It's also common to hammer on to notes on other strings - we don't need to have played that string before hammering on, that's a fallacy. It also means that we can hold onto the previous note long enough so that one doesn't get clipped short.

Then there's sliding. That will definitely mean smooth playing (with careful timing), but will take the next lot of notes into the next position, as sliding essentially uses the same finger up (and down) the same string. So knowing how and where the next door neighbour pattern for the next pent. pattern goes is essential.

And lastly - direction of picking does come into the equation, in my book. If the next note is on the next string, it's going to be a smoother transition for the last pick to go in that direction. As a teenager, I spent hours working out picking direction in order to sort out the stuttering my playing sounded like, as often, I'd be picking the opposite way. Eventually, it became second nature, and hardly ever gets addressed these days. Coupled with the fact that somewhere along the line, I developed hybrid picking (using pick and fingers), unintentionally, but it certainly helps fluidity!

Comment: +1 All of those encourage holding the previous note till the last split second which promotes fluidity. However I don’t agree with your comment regarding picking string to string in the same direction being a smoother transition. It can be if that’s what one learns and gets used to but there are many people out there that feel alternating strokes are smoother. You can’t really say one is smoother. I favor alternating strokes because of the strong/weak aspect of steady notes and the perpetual motion of the picking hand but I sometimes will cross strings in one direction depending on the music.

Comment: @JohnBelzaguy - I can say, if it's smoother for me. But there are loads of players, including, it seems, yourself, who find alternating picking works better. It just isn't so productive for me.

Comment: I’m curious, there have to be times when you might be doing a string crossing up but the lower string ends on a upstroke. Do you just do an up and down in that instance or do you change your picking pattern beforehand to turn it around? Or is it just instinctual at this point for you?

Comment: It's become instinctive mostly, although if it's a particular phrase I need to play, I'll go through it slowly to work out pick direction, or incorporate a finger. Mostly it just happens. There's a bass player I know who has developed a slightly similar idea - he mutes all four strings (on a 5er) so only the string being played can ever be heard, Watching is fascinating. Doesn't seem to think about it any more, it just happens. But what a clean player!